# golang cast a string to net.IPNet type

Tags: casting, go

I have a slice of strings that are in CIDR notation.  They are both ipv4 and ipv6 and I need them cast into the type net.IPNet.

How would I do this in golang?

example strings:

192.168.1.1/24
fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381::/64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As cnicutar says use `net.ParseCIDR`.

This is a working example on how to actually use it.

http://play.golang.org/p/Wtqy56LS2Y

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ipList := []string{"192.168.1.1/24", "fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381::/64"}
    for i := 0; i < len(ipList); i += 1 {
        ip, ipnet, err := net.ParseCIDR(ipList[i])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error", ipList[i], err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(ipList[i], "-> ip:", ip, " net:", ipnet)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need. Ultimately I need to have the network and check to see if an ip is that network. I want to store this string as net.IPNet and then check against that type.

my struct looks like
type IpData struct {  
 ShortDesc string  
 LongDesc  string  
 Subnet    net.IPNet  
 Note      string  
}  

I then have a slice of struct that I need to iterate my passed in ip against the Subnet.

Comment: Do note that ParseCIDR returns IPNet as a pointer, so depending on how you use the result, you may have to dereference it, if the usage calls for the non-pointer version, so it would be *ipnet in the example above, when referring to the variable's value.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you want casting; instead I think you want [`ParseCIDR`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ParseCIDR)

```
func ParseCIDR(s string) (IP, *IPNet, error)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/). CIDR subnets, IP addresses and masks all use the same type in the IPAddress library, `ipaddr.IPAddress`, making code simpler.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    parseAddr("192.168.1.1/24")
    parseAddr("fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381::/64")
}

func parseAddr(cidrStr string) {
    cidr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidrStr)
    subnet, addr := cidr.GetAddress().ToPrefixBlock(), cidr.GetHostAddress()
    var ipNet = net.IPNet{
        IP:   subnet.GetNetIP(),
        Mask: subnet.GetNetworkMask().Bytes(),
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nsubnet: %s\naddress: %s\nIPNet: %+v\n", subnet, addr, ipNet)
}
```

Output:

```
subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
address: 192.168.1.1
IPNet: {IP:192.168.1.0 Mask:ffffff00}

subnet: fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381::/64
address: fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381::
IPNet: {IP:fd04:3e42:4a4e:3381:: Mask:ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000}
```